# Ballot problem with initial votes counted

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

> In an election where candidate $A$ receives $p$ votes and candidate $B$ receives $q$ votes with $p > q$, what is the probability that $A$ will be strictly ahead of $B$ throughout the count **given that the first $m$ counted votes belong to $A$**?

The part that is boldface is what I have added to the original problem. The answer to the original problem is $(p-q)/(p+q)$. I tried to find a recursive formula to solve this but I am really getting confused. Is that addressed in the literature?

Comment: That would be a finite (random) walk. But since it is not completely random, you will have to count the paths.

Comment: It's a variant of **Bertrand's ballot problem**. These keywords hopefully may help you find relevant documents on the web...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had just learned this in class so I might make a mistake, please point out if you see one!

First note that if $a\leq b$ there's no way that A would stay strictly ahead all the time because A would eventually lose or tie. So we consider $a>b$. Let's think about this in terms of lattice paths. A lattice path is a path from (0,0) to (a,b) only taking Right or Up steps. Each way of counting the votes corresponds to a lattice path, say counting A once is going Right and counting B once is going Up.
[image]
So what you're asking is if the first $m$ steps are Right steps, how many paths stay strictly below the $y=x$ line. If we restrict ourself to look at the red box, we'd reduce the problem to "how many paths stay strictly below the $y=x+m$ line, with the goal being $(a-m,b)$."

Now let's count the "bad paths", i.e. the paths that first hit $y=x+m$ at $(r,r+m)$. Fix such a path $P$. We'd "reflect" the path from $(r,r+m)$ on by changing its Right steps to Up steps, and its Up steps to Right steps. Let's denote the new path $P'$. Let $(R,U)$ denote the number of Right steps and number of Up steps. Now we know

|  | Before | After |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $P$ | $(R,U)=(r,r+m)$ | $(R,U)=(a-m-r,b-r-m)$ |
| $P'$ | $(R,U)=(r,r+m)$ | $(R,U)=(b-r-m,a-m-r)$ |

This is because after taking $r$ Right steps, to get to our horizontal goal of $a-m$, we need $a-m-r$ more steps, and the same reasoning applies for the vertical steps. And the third column is just the Right steps in $P$ became the Up steps in $P'$ and vice versa.

So let's figure out where the reflection of the bad paths end up at. In total, we take $b-m=r+b-r-m$ Right steps and $a=a-m-r+r+m$ Up steps, so we end up at $(b-m,a)$. Note there a 1-1 correspondence between the bad paths $P$ and any path that end up at $(b-m,a)$. We already know how to transform a bad path to a path that ends up at $(b-m,a)$. Now any path that end up at $(b-m,a)$ must hit the line $y=x+m$. Since $a>b$, we know that $a>(b-m)+m$, so to get to $a$, you must pass the $y=x+m$ line. We can transform this path to a bad path by reflecting again at the first point of crossing.

So the number of bad paths is equal to the number of paths that ends up at $(b-m,a)$, and there are $\binom{a+b-m}{a}$ of them.

Now back to the main problem. To get the probability, we use $\frac{|\text{good paths}|}{|\text{all paths}|}$. The number of good paths is total number of paths minus the bad paths. The total number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(a,b)$ with the first $m$ steps being horizontal is $\binom{a+b-m}{b}$. So the number of good paths is $\binom{a+b-m}{b}-\binom{a+b-m}{a}$. So the probability is
$$\frac{\binom{a+b-m}{b}-\binom{a+b-m}{a}}{\binom{a+b-m}{b}}$$
If you simplify it it becomes $\frac{a_{(m)}-b_{(m)}}{a_{(m)}}$